# Magento 2: how to disable zoom using gestures in the whole site?

Tags: magento2, rwd, design, mobile, zoom

Users can zoom in and zoom out on any page using gestures (index finger and thumb).

How can I prevent that behavior?

I'm using custom theme which inherits from Blank theme.

Answer (score 0):

That effect can be changed in this file **Magento_Catalog/css/source/module/_listings.less**:

```
.product-item-info .product-image-container:hover,
.product-item-info .product-image-container.active {
    transform: scale(1);
}
```